# how to change the parent's template (ui-view) by clicking a child element?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a div as : `<div ui-view="template1"></div>`

```
<!--template1.html-->
<button>click me</button>
```

when i click this button, the view should be changed from template1 to template2.

`
how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `<div ui-view="{{view}}"></div>`

and then: `<button ng-click="view = 'template2' ">click me</button>`

Didnt actually tested, try it out and see if it helps...

Krisalay found the solution, I will post under mine:

```
$state.go('^.template2');
```

Comment: Try changing to this: ng-click="view = 'template2' ". If it doesnt work, Are they using the same controller?

Comment: i got the answer, it will work by using: $state.go('^.template2');

Comment: Glad you found the solution =)

Comment: thnx for ur effort